# CountDownTimer and ValueEventListener doesn't work

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, countdowntimer

From the logcat i realized that countDownTimer is just skipped in my code, and the firebase listener is not always working correctly.
Any idea what might be wrong?

All i'm trying to do is make my customer wait for employer response for 15 seconds, if he accepted within the time we move on, if not we try with the next employer in the list and so on.

My code:

```
package com.example.eltobgy.yala.Activities.OrderPackageActivities;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.example.eltobgy.yala.Activities.MainActivity;
import com.example.eltobgy.yala.Models.Package;
import com.example.eltobgy.yala.PackageOnTheWayActivity;
import com.example.eltobgy.yala.R;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import static com.example.eltobgy.yala.Activities.MainActivity.currentUser;
import static com.example.eltobgy.yala.Activities.MainActivity.mDatabaseUsersReference;

public class WaitingForDeliverymanAcceptanceActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private static final String LOG_TAG=WaitingForDeliverymanAcceptanceActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private int i = 0;
    private String id;
    private DatabaseReference acceptedReference;
    private String onlineSetPackage = "";
    private Package mPackage;
    boolean isAccepted;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_watingfor_deliveryman_acceptance);
        mPackage = (Package) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("package");


        findDeliveryman();
    }

    private void findDeliveryman() {
        Log.e("OrderPackageMapActivity", "entered find delivery man function");

        while (i < OrderPackageMapActivity.onlineDeliveryMenList.size()) {
            id = OrderPackageMapActivity.onlineDeliveryMenList.get(i).getId();

            acceptedReference = MainActivity.mDatabaseOnlineDeliverymenReference.child(id).child("acceptedOrder");
            acceptedReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if ((boolean) dataSnapshot.getValue() == true) {
                        isAccepted = true;
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"isAccepted is true");
                    } else {
                        isAccepted = false;
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "isAccepted is false");
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });

            onlineSetPackage = OrderPackageMapActivity.onlineDeliveryMenList.get(i).getCurrentPackageID();

            DatabaseReference onlineCurrentPackageRef = MainActivity.mDatabaseOnlineDeliverymenReference.child(id).child("currentPackageID");

            if ((onlineSetPackage.equals("")) || (onlineSetPackage == null) || (onlineSetPackage.isEmpty())) {
                onlineCurrentPackageRef.setValue(packageID);
                MainActivity.currentUser.setAttachedDeliveryId(id);
                Log.e(LOG_TAG,"package is set to:"+id);
                CountDownTimer countDownTimer=new CountDownTimer(15000, 1000) {

                    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                        //mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                        //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG,"seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
                    }

                    public void onFinish() {
                        checkRequestAcceptance();
                    }

                };
                countDownTimer.start();

            } else {
                i++;
                Log.e("i =", String.valueOf(i));
            }

        }
    }

    private void checkRequestAcceptance() {
        if (isAccepted) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "I accepet");
            mDatabaseUsersReference.child(currentUser.getId()).child("attachedDeliveryId").setValue(id);

            Intent intent = new Intent(WaitingForDeliverymanAcceptanceActivity.this, PackageOnTheWayActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        } else {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "I refuse");
            i++;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: are you getting any error??

Comment: No, it's just not working like it's supposed to.

Comment: you can use a handler bro

Comment: Personally I think it is bad practice to get the database reference from another `Activity` in this case `MainActivity`. The preferred method is to use `FirebaseDatabase
                .getInstance()
                .getReference()
                .child`

Comment: @Barns but if he has multiple child wand to get the data from a fixed chiled then it it ok method but for 1 child you are correct

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava :: The OP states quite clearly "...and the firebase listener is not always working correctly"  Hhmmm. I wonder why? `MainActivity` has nothing to do with `WaitingForDeliverymanAcceptanceActivity` at least it shouldn't. Referencing code in this manner is just bad practice.

Comment: thx mate i learned too @Barns I will not do that but can tell me how will i sen on multiple children like in a music app i use to get the album id and from there i get the child so only way possible is to send the id to new fragment and do the search thats why i use to think it only way  . hope you will give some hint

Comment: @NeelaySrivastava :: There is a clear difference between the example of two separate `Activtiy`s one of which is no longer active and the example of a dependent `Fragment` which will be hosted inside an `Activity`.  Often `Fragment` and host `Activity` need to share information (like in your music example). The OP is clearly using code from the `MainActivity` which is no longer active while the `WaitingForDeliverymanAcceptanceActivity` is active. If the OP wishes to reuse code in both activities, that code should create a separate class.

Comment: THX @Barns got it clear

Comment: Also consider that the OP has an object `mDatabaseUsersReference`  inside the `checkRequestAcceptance()` method this is not referenced in the example code. How is that supposed to work.